# 2 Disks with the same name, how do I delete one?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I initially boot-camped a disk into a windows partition, and wanted to delete it. Initially I thought formatting it to free space would work, but it didn't. I tried again and accidentally formatted it to the type `Mac OS Extended`. Problem is, that's the name of my main HD as well.

I can't even re-name/repair/verify it

[image: This is what happens when I try to verify or repair it]

I do have the logical Id's for both of them though, and know which one has which logical ID.

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group AEDB2CC4-9034-444E-A973-AD57E668F322
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         134140436480 B (134.1 GB)
    Free Space:   8953856 B (9.0 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 17931EB1-83F7-458D-B2B4-497D111AE88A
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     134140436480 B (134.1 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 18F33EE2-F845-480F-B794-DB888CD06F22
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Conversion Status:       Complete
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   Yes
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume A3DCD237-4353-4A29-BCA2-5689B3869590
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          134140436480 B (134.1 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   Complete
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

All I'm trying to do is merge the disk to my main HD.

HELP!

Comment: Have you been able to find an answer for this?